# Remove borders from tabView in PrimeNG

Tags: html, css, primeng

I am trying to remove the borders from the p-tabView element without any success by setting the following:

```
<p-tabView style='border: 0px;'>
```

When I remove the border in the developer tools for the styling of the element

```
body .ui-widget-content
```

it works. Anyone any idea where and how I can specify this in my html/css?

Answer (score 2):

It worked this way:

```
:host ::ng-deep .ui-widget-content {
   border: 0px;
}
```

The ::ngdeep you mentioned got me on the correct track :)

Answer (score 1):

this worked for TabMenu:

```
.p-menuitem-link {
  border: none;
}
```

you can try the same on:
https://primeng.org/tabview#style
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your CSS :

```
::ng-deep .ui-widget-header {
  border: none;
}
```

Comment: thanx, but it doesn't work. Do I need to specify anything else in the html?